# Not Able to boot in to Elementary OS

Tags: elementaryos

I am having lenovo G 505 Laptop with preinstalled windows 8.  i installed elementary os after recreating partitions a fresh .  the installation process was successful.  on restarting the machine i got the elementary and advance elementary menu.  i click on elementary and it does not goes ahead.  it just gave me a blank screen on clicking elementary menu.

i though there was some issue with the installation, hence i re installed elementary, this time i choose other option i.e. i did not made any partition and install elementary.  the process was successful but again when i am trying to login to elementary nothing happens.  it just stays on the blank screen,

request help here.

Comment: At the screen  where nothing happens, press `Alt + Tab` and send a screenshot of the screen which comes

Comment: sir here i see no option to attach a screen shot.

Comment: Upload the pic on upload.disroot.org and paste the link here